# What are the rules for nesting @'s in Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've just started with Razor (v3) and it's fine, but I don't understand the rules behind when you need to use the @ sign.

Here is an example from my current project.

In this code:

```
@if (ViewBag.ForcePublic == null && User.Identity.GetUserId() == @Model.Seller.Id)
        {                              
            <h2>Listing Status</h2>
            switch (Model.Status)
            {
```

If I put a @ in front of the switch statement, I get a runtime error saying that I don't need to nest @ signs.

However, in this code:

```
@if(!Model.BizAddress.StreetAddress.IsEmpty()) {
                 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BizAddress.StreetAddress);
            }
```

Not only do I **not** get a syntax error (as one would expect, considering the example above), if I don't include the @ sign in front of Html.DisplayFor, my StreetAddress is not printed. Instead it silently fails!

I would like to understand why this is happening so that I can avoid subtle bugs this might cause in the future.

I suspect that the root cause has something to do with the fact that the templating (I think) is analogous to a preprocessor step, and the scoping of the C# code is only known at runtime, so these two examples are structurally the same after both steps take place (preprocess, compile and run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` in Razor is used for two different purposes:

1- You denote the start of a code block with Razor using a `@` character. This is like `<% %>` in Web Forms.

2- Inline expressions (variables and functions) start with `@` (for writing content on the page). This is like `<%: %>` or `<% Response.Write() %>` in Web Forms.

In your code, the `@` character before `if` denotes the start of a code block. The end of the block is the end `}` of the `if` block. You don't need to and are not allowed to use `@` for anything in between. But, the `@` before `Html.DisplayFor()` is used for an inline expression. In fact, you should not put a semi-colon at the end of that line, otherwise the semi-colon will be displayed after the display name on the page.

Look at this [quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) for more details.